# Type classes vs Data Types in functional Libraries in scala such as Cats and ScalaZ

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats

ScalaZ and Cats both have this notion of type class and Data Types.

Although I understand type classes, and type classes instances, I don't understand their use of the term *"data types"*.

Things like `Kleisi` or `Either` are referred to as *"Data types"* - why? My understanding is that they are generic functionality implemented "probably" using those type classes, however even in the book FP Programing in Scala, they are not referred to as *"Data types"*.

I wonder where the term comes from?

Examples:

- https://typelevel.org/cats/
- https://scalaz.github.io/7/

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I did the recommended edit. I guess Data Types is used in cats while Data types is used in Scalaz.

Answer (score 7):

I would say it's mostly Haskell influence:

- everything that you would declare as `class` in Haskell is called "type class", and is usually located in `cats._`
- everything that you would declare as `data` in Haskell is called "data type", and ends up in `cats.data._`
- instances of type classes that you would usually implement with the `instance` keyword in Haskell are all in `cats.instances._`

"Type class" is a reserved phrase with a rather precise meaning: it's a kind of language feature or design pattern that enables ad-hoc polymorphism. It occurs across multiple languages. The implementation details can vary (it's built-in in Haskell, but simulated through classes with (higher-kinded) type parameters in Scala), but the essence is more or less the same.

"Data Type" does not seem to have any such precise meaning - at least it's not in the same league as "Algebraic Data Types" or "Generalized Algebraic Data Types". My current guess is that it's a more or less colloquial term for "all the stuff that you would declare with the `data` keyword in Haskell", so, essentially, it's just bunch of classes that represent some data structures that can be used and composed in a type-safe manner.

Comment: Yep, you've hit the nail on the head. You lovely Scala folk want to make us Haskellers feel at home <3